# Pylint checker: Format function is not called on a string

Tags: python, pylint

Code works fine in wing etc. 
Pylint isn't very happy with me keep getting the style error:

> format function is not called on str (misplaced-format-function)

```
def print_daily_totals(rainfalls):
    '''t'''
    day = 0
    return_list = []
    for row in rainfalls:
        total = 0
        for i in row:
            total += i
        return_list.append(total)
    for value in return_list:
        print("Day {} total: {}").format(day, value)

rain = [ 
      [0, 7, 9],
      [4, 6, 2],
      [0, 0, 0],
      [10, 23, 5],
      [20, 0, 0]
]
print_daily_totals(rain)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a misplaced bracket:

```
print("Day {} total: {}").format(day, value)
```

should be

```
print("Day {} total: {}".format(day, value))
```

Though I find it hard to believe that the code works normally, as you suggest. `print` returns `None` and has no method `format`.